# Can we change the convert certificate from pem into jks or pkcs12 without private key?

Tags: java, openssl, certificate, pem, jks

I have a certificates (public key) in a standardized X.509 format (without private key) and I want to convert it into JKS or PKCS12 format as these formats are only supported by my application.

Is it possible to convert it without private key?